# Python list.sort(key=lambda x: ...) type hints

Tags: python, lambda, types, type-hinting, mypy

I am sorting a list of dicts based on a key like below

```
my_function() -> list[dict]:
    data: list[dict] = []

    # Populate data ...

    if condition:
        data.sort(key=lambda x: x["position"])

    return data
```

However mypy complains about `Returning Any from function declared to return "Union[SupportsDunderLT[Any], SupportsDunderGT[Any]]"`. Is it possible to update the above snippet so that mypy doesn't raise a `no-any-return` error?

**EDIT**

Versions: Python 3.10.9 and mypy 1.0.0 (compiled: yes)

Comment: assuming line 1 should be `def my_function() -> list[dict]:` otherwise you have syntax errors

Comment: I got no errors from mypy 1.0.0 with python 3.11.1 when running this

Comment: can you post a more complete example?

Comment: Note that this requires `--strict` mypy flag to reproduce, and here's [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=93584d925aa1a1f243f48b51d573adf8). The problem is in missing generic `dict` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by [@SisodiaMonu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75471999/14401160) should work. However, seems that your example uses dict more like a JS object, so all keys have semantic meaning. For such cases there is a [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict), which allows you to annotate all dict keys with types. This is important, if your dict can contain some objects of other types: if it's `{'position': 1, 'key': 'foo'}`, then the type would've been `dict[str, int | str]`, and `mypy` will point out invalid comparison (`int | str` is not comparable). With `TypedDict`, this problem won't arise:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class MyItem(TypedDict):
    position: int
    key: str


condition = True

def my_function() -> list[MyItem]:
    data: list[MyItem] = []

    # Populate data ...

    if condition:
        data.sort(key=lambda x: x["position"])

    return data
```

You can try this solution in [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=6b564368f4d5ed44e76becc15f506f9a).